# SQL Server: Maximum character length of object names

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What is the maximum character length of object name (e.g. constraint, column) in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

128 characters. This is the max length of  the [`sysname`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191240(v=sql.105)#sysname) datatype (`nvarchar(128)`).

Answer (score 63):

Yes, it is 128, except for **temp tables**, whose names can only be up to **116** character long.
It is perfectly [explained here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/05/01/sql-server-maximum-allowable-length-of-characters-for-temp-objects-is-116-guest-post-by-balmukund-lakhani/).

And the verification can be easily made with the following script contained in the blog post before:

```
DECLARE @i NVARCHAR(800)
SELECT @i = REPLICATE('A', 116)
SELECT @i = 'CREATE TABLE #'+@i+'(i int)'
PRINT @i
EXEC(@i)
```

Comment: I think that by "comprobation" you might have meant "test" or "verification". Am I right?

Comment: @Jaime Thanks for teaching me a new word, you should have left it in the answer.

Answer (score 28):

You can also use this script to figure out more info:

```
EXEC sp_server_info
```

The result will be something like that:

```
attribute_id | attribute_name        | attribute_value
-------------|-----------------------|-----------------------------------
           1 | DBMS_NAME             | Microsoft SQL Server
           2 | DBMS_VER              | Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.6020.0
          10 | OWNER_TERM            | owner
          11 | TABLE_TERM            | table
          12 | MAX_OWNER_NAME_LENGTH | 128
          13 | TABLE_LENGTH          | 128
          14 | MAX_QUAL_LENGTH       | 128
          15 | COLUMN_LENGTH         | 128
          16 | IDENTIFIER_CASE       | MIXED
           ⋮  ⋮                       ⋮
           ⋮  ⋮                       ⋮
           ⋮  ⋮                       ⋮
```