# SQL Server 2008 Operator Email Name length : Max Characters | Email addresses

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, email, notifications

In SQL Server 2008, if one would want multiple email addresses to be notified when a Job Succeeds or Fails, he would have to Assign Email notification to an Operator in Job Properties -> Notifications.

In my case, due to email domain length, I can only enter 3 email address in Operator's "Email Name" Field.

Is there any way out so that i can allow notification to 3+ email addresses?

Note : An option to assign multiple operator to a Job notification also would do.

Answer (score 2):

Only up to 128 characters. This is the max length of the sysname datatype

See:

[SQL Server: Maximum character length of object names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808332/sql-server-maximum-character-length-of-object-names)

Answer (score 0):

The Email Name length in SQL Server 2008 R2 is 100 characters. The problem is that if you type a longer value it will cut it.